# Joiner Transformation in Informatica PowerCenter - Trouble in joining duplicate values from source with target

Tags: informatica-powercenter, joiner

I  have following scenario

```
Source 1:    Category_DTL

Category_ID    Date         Value

1       20180101    10
1       20180110    12
2       20180101    14
3       20180101    15
4       20180101    10


Source 2:    Category_Master

Category_ID    Name Comments
1       abc C1
2       xyz C2
3       qwe C3
4       rty C4
5       qqq C5
6       www C6


I need output as:

Category_ID    Date         Value   Name    Comments
1       20180101    10  abc C1
1       20180110    12  abc C1
2       20180101    14  xyz C2
3       20180101    15  qwe C3
4       20180101    10  rty C4



But When I use joiner transformation in Informatica PowerCenter, I get following output:
Category_ID    Date         Value   Name    Comments
1       20180101    10  abc C1
1       20180110    12  
2       20180101    14  xyz C2
3       20180101    15  qwe C3
4       20180101    10  rty C4
```

It only matches first record from source with master table in case source have duplicate values on key column used in joining condition.

```
Join conditon > Category_Master.Category_ID = Category_DTL.Category_ID
Join type used > Detail outer Join
Master Table > Category_Master
Detail Table > Category_DTL
```

Any suggestion to get desired result is appreciated.

Comment: I cant see whats wrong from the requirement you've shared... how about telling us what error you're getting?

Comment: The code seems fine - as long as the example given here matches your actual code. Can you share a screenshot of your joiner? Otherwise limit the dataset to Category_ID=1 and run the code in debugger. Share the results or errors if you get any.